# Dynamically add instance variables via decorator to a class in Python

Tags: python

I want to instrument a class via a decorator, to add some **instance** variables that are specified by the author of the class.

I started with the following code, but this just adds **class** variables and I want **instance** variables (those that are normally 'declared' in __ init __)

What is a pythonic way to do this, while allowing the class author control over what they put in __ init __?

```
def add_list_attributes(klass):
    for attribute in klass.list_attributes:
        setattr(klass, attribute, [])

    return klass

@add_list_attributes
class Person(object):

    list_attributes = [
        'phone_numbers'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

p1 = Person()
p1.phone_numbers.append('01234')

print p1.phone_numbers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `__new__` method:

```
def add_list_attributes(klass):
    def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)
        for attribute in klass.list_attributes:
            setattr(result, attribute, [])
        return result
    klass.__new__ = staticmethod(new)
    return klass

@add_list_attributes
class Person(object):
    list_attributes = [
        'phone_numbers'
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        pass

p1 = Person()
p2 = Person()
p1.phone_numbers.append('01234')

print p1.phone_numbers, p2.phone_numbers
```

Comment: `super` is the way to go here; +1

Comment: But I'm not sure whether this works if the superclass `__init__` function takes more than one argument.

Comment: then why not pass on the args/kwargs to the `__new__` call?: `super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: where can i find definition for setattr and staticmethod

Answer (score 2):

You would have to wrap `__init__()` in a separate function that would call the original method, then add its own attributes to the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by wrapping the `__init__` method to do your bidding, and then call the original `__init__`:

```
def add_list_attributes(klass):
    old_init = klass.__init__
    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for attribute in klass.list_attributes:
            setattr(self, attribute, [])
        old_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    klass.__init__ = new_init
    return klass

@add_list_attributes
class Person(object):

    list_attributes = [
        'phone_numbers'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

p1 = Person()
p1.phone_numbers.append('01234')
p2 = Person()
p2.phone_numbers.append('56789')

print p1.phone_numbers
print p2.phone_numbers
```

Comment: You might use the `functools.wraps` decorator to carry over the name and docstring of the original `__init__`.